# How to use cat a file and count number of lines in a file using import scala.sys.process package

Tags: scala, hadoop, package

I have a file name in a scala varible. I would like to pass the variable to cat the file and count the number of lines. I'm trying to implement using scala.sys.process package.

**val file = ("hadoop fs -ls /user/landing/data"#|"sort -k6,7"#|"tail -n1").!!.trim**
file: String = -rw-r--r--   3 pa_raviko5 hive       3093 2019-11-22 00:18 /user/landing/data/file.csv

**val file_path = file.split(" ").last.trim**
file_path: String = /user/landing/data/file.csv

scala> **Seq("hadoop", "fs",  "-cat", file_path, "|", "wc", "-l").!!****
cat: `|': No such file or directory
cat:`wc': No such file or directory
cat: `-l': No such file or directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
  ... 53 elided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use pipe operator `|` as part of your `Seq(...).!!`. It is shell thing and scala don't know what to do with it. You can call bash like that:

```scala
Seq("bash", "-c", s"""hadoop fs -cat "$file_path" | wc -l""").!!
```

You should escape your path with `"` as shown above.
PS: please use scala's naming convention where appropriate (`filePath` instead of `file_path`)